# Why getRelativeTimeSpanString is returning incorrect text?

Tags: java, android

I'm calling getRelativeTimeSpanString like this

```
DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
   date.getTime(), System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
```

For some reason, instead of returning `"Hace 5 horas"` as it should be from the resource below, it returns `"Desde 5 horas"`.

```
<plurals name="num_hours_ago">
    <item quantity="one" msgid="9150797944610821849">"Hace 1 hora"</item>
    <item quantity="other" msgid="2467273239587587569">"Hace <xliff:g id="COUNT">%d</xliff:g> horas"</item>
</plurals>
```

How can I detect where that text is coming from? I explored the res folder on sdk and couldn't find that text.